# 2 way Sync programatically in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

I am working on a Windows Desktop Application using C# where files/folders are transferred from web server to a particular user's folder in the computer and vice versa. (Something like SkyDrive where the files/folders from the application is copied to the user's skyDrive folder)

So right now I am able to copy the files to and from the web server if the system is connected to internet. If I create a file/folder offline and the next time I connect to internet I need to copy the newly created ones to the web server. Basically a 2 way sync while offline. Is there any possible way to implement this.? Can I implement this with Sync Framework ? Please help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft Sync Framework** can fit for your need

> A comprehensive synchronization platform that enables collaboration and offline access for applications, services, and devices with support for any data type, any data store, any transfer protocol, and any network topology.

- Add sync support to new and existing applications, services, and devices
- Enable collaboration and offline capabilities for any application
- Roam and share information from any data store, over any protocol, and over any network configuration
- Leverage sync capabilities exposed in Microsoft technologies to create sync ecosystems
- Extend the architecture to support custom data types including files

[Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx)

[SynkToy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16112/Quietly-run-Microsoft-s-SyncToy)